# JavaFX draw Multi shape using multiple points

Tags: java, javafx-2, line

I have an arraylist of Point. I want to draw lines out the points. Here is what I have done.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrPoint.size(); i++) {
            Point startPoint = arrPoint.get(i);
            Point endPoint = null;
            if (i == arrPoint.size()) {
                endPoint = arrPoint.get(0);
            } else {
                endPoint = arrPoint.get(i + 1);
            }
            Line line = new Line();
            line.setStartX(startPoint.getCoordinateX());
            line.setEndX(endPoint.getCoordinateX());
            line.setStartY(startPoint.getCoordinateY());
            line.setEndY(endPoint.getCoordinateY());
            box.getChildren().add(line);
        }
```

My Point cass is like

```
public class Point {
    private double coordinateX;
    private double coordinateY;

    public Point(double coordinateX, double coordinateY) {
        this.coordinateX = coordinateX;
        this.coordinateY = coordinateY;
    }

    public void setCoordinateX(double coordinateX) {
        this.coordinateX = coordinateX;
    }

    public void setCoordinateY(double coordinateY) {
        this.coordinateY = coordinateY;
    }

    public double getCoordinateX() {
        return coordinateX;
    }

    public double getCoordinateY() {
        return coordinateY;
    }
}
```

My code is displayed blank. I am new to JavaFx. Can I get any help?

Comment: There simply is not enough info to identify the problem. We do not know what kind of layout `box` is or where in the scene it's located. furthermore we know nothing about the input data. The lines could simply not be part of the visual area... BTW: there is the [`Polygon` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Polygon.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the points before you can loop over the points to draw.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        primaryStage.setTitle("Draw line");


        Group g = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(g, 550, 550,Color.web("0x0000FF",1.0));

        ObservableList<Point> arrPoint = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        Point point1 = new Point(100, 200);
        Point point2 = new Point(300, 400);

        arrPoint.addAll(point1, point2);

        for (int i = 0; i < arrPoint.size()-1; i++) {
            Point startPoint = arrPoint.get(i);
            Point endPoint = null;
            if (i == arrPoint.size()) {
                endPoint = arrPoint.get(0);
            } else {
                endPoint = arrPoint.get(i + 1);
            }
            Line line = new Line();
            line.setStartX(startPoint.getCoordinateX());
            line.setEndX(endPoint.getCoordinateX());
            line.setStartY(startPoint.getCoordinateY());
            line.setEndY(endPoint.getCoordinateY());
            g.getChildren().add(line);
        }



        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

I hope it can help you some.